# Nodejs - Increase heap size in express.js project

Tags: node.js, express, v8

I have an express.js project (typescript) with the following commands to package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "npm run build && npm run watch",
    "build": "npm run build-ts && npm run tslint",
    "serve": "nodemon dist/server.js",
    "watch": "concurrently -k -p \"[{name}]\" -n \"TypeScript,Node\" -c \"yellow.bold,cyan.bold,green.bold\" \"npm run watch-ts\" \"npm run serve\"",
    "test": "jest --forceExit",
    "build-ts": "tsc",
    "watch-ts": "tsc -w",
    "tslint": "tslint -c tslint.json -p tsconfig.json",
    "debug": "npm run build && npm run watch-debug",
    "serve-debug": "nodemon --inspect dist/server.js",
    "watch-debug": "concurrently -k -p \"[{name}]\" -n \"Sass,TypeScript,Node\" -c \"yellow.bold,cyan.bold,green.bold\" \"npm run watch-ts\" \"npm run serve-debug\"",
    "angular-build": "cd app && ng build --prod --output-path=../dist/app/ --deploy-url= --no-progress --aot true"
},
```

I know that the command to increase heap memory size is --max-old-space-size but i don't know where to put it....

All the examples i saw are

```
node --max-old-space-size=4096 myapp.js
```

but I don't run my app this way... I just run "npm start"

I use this code to check the current heap size

```
let v8 = require("v8");
let totalHeapSizeInGB = (((v8.getHeapStatistics().total_available_size) / 1024 / 1024 / 1024).toFixed(2));
console.log(`*******************************************`);
console.log(`Total Heap Size ~${totalHeapSizeInGB}GB`);
console.log(`*******************************************`);
```

Comment: `npm start` runs the `start` script, which runs `serve`,  which then runs `serve`. Change serve to `nodemon dist/server.js --max-old-space-size=4096`

Comment: I have already test this with no lack

Comment: Without the flag and your code I get `1.39GB`, with the flag I get `0.02GB`, so it's doing something.

Comment: Still no lack....

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
nodemon --max-old-space-size=4096 dist/server.js (this is OK)
nodemon dist/server.js --max-old-space-size=4096 (this is NOT OK)
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to ur package.json file and replace "start" like this 
[Screenshot package.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2AeNl.jpg)

Comment: Single external link answers are not great for SO. The idea is to make the question completely stand-alone, so maybe provide a brief synopsis of the relevant details.